# Getting text value from textbox webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to get the text value from the text box. I tried using gettext() but it gives me empty value. Please suggest how to get the email address value from the text box. [Refer the image for html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwhbV.png)

Comment: What did you try? Insert your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using `getAttribute`: `findElement(By.id("EmailAddress")).getAttribute("value")`

Based on `WebElement` `getText()` docs:

```
/**
   * Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, including sub-elements,
   * without any leading or trailing whitespace.
   *
   * @return The innerText of this element.
   */
  String getText();
```

Hence, `<a name="foo">bar</a>` `getText()` will give you `"bar"`

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a question insert always your attempts. Don't insert an image to show a code (or html). Prefer insert directly the code. Using your shared infos, the interested web element has as id `EmailAddress`. So, you could try:

```
findElement(By.id("EmailAddress")).getText();
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried exactly the same code you have mentioned. findElement(By.id("EmailAddress")).getText();

But it gives me an empty value. You can see in the code that there is no text value in it.

Comment: It is a MVC page with Angular JS. They getting values from Angular JS and showing it over the text field directly @Davide Patti